# create toast when non-unique record entered in SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, unique, toast

Newby here.
I create a table.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists producttable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
            + "productidno"
            + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + "productname"
            + " TEXT,"
            + "productprice" + " TEXT,"
            + "t1" + " TEXT," //two added,  watch commas after "TEXT,"
            + "t2" + " TEXT)");
}
```

When I try to add a non-unique productidno, the row is not added, however the program continues, no message, no nothing.  I would like a toast to appear telling the user that a non-unique entry was not added so that they are aware and need to change to a unique productidno.
I do not know where to place this.  Any help with sample code would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Show the code you use to insert a row. If you use `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` read in the docs about the return value

Comment: Thanks, your reply helped me place the toast.  I'm new to this, how do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: I have written my comment as an answer. You can either click on the checkmark beneath my answer or write your own, more detailed answer and check it (you may have to wait some time before you can check your answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` read in the docs about the return value.